# How can I re-display a second conditionally hidden <div> when the first condition is changed?

Tags: jquery

I have two questions on a form, with radio buttons for `Option1` and `Option2` and am using jQuery to show/hide additional questions within hidden `<div>` elements. If you answer "Yes" to Option 1, a first conditional `<div>` is shown with an additional question about Option 2. If the answer to Option 2 is "Yes", then a second conditional `<div>` is displayed with additional questions.

If the user changes the Option 1 question to "No" after picking "Yes", I hide the second conditional `<div>`. However, if the user selects "Yes" again to Option 1, the answer for Option 2 remains "Yes", but the second conditional `<div>` does not show because there is no `change` event - the user would have to pick "No" then "Yes" again to show the second conditional `<div>`.

I'm not sure how to handle this with code, whether I should try to reset the radio button state or handle it in some other fashion. Any advice is appreciated.

Here is my jQuery code for the show/hide conditions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[name='Option1']").on ( "change", function() {

            if (this.value == "Yes") {
                $('#option1Display, #option1Display input').show().removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else {
                $('#option1Display, #option1Display input,\
                #option2Display, #option2Display input').hide().attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
    });
        $("#option1Display, #option1Display input").hide().attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[name='Option2']").on ( "change", function() {

            if (this.value == "Yes") {
                $('#option2Display, #option2Display input').show().removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else {
                $('#option2Display, #option2Display input').hide().attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
    });
        $("#option2Display, #option2Display input").hide().attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
</script>
```

EDIT: Sorry all, my markup is run through a CMS that produces a lot of `<div>` elements with various CSS classes, but I will try to reproduce the markup below with:

```
<div>
<label>Option 1 Question</label>
<ol>
    <li>   
        <label>
            <input name="Option1" type="radio" value="No">
            No
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>   
        <label>
            <input name="Option1" type="radio" value="Yes">
            Yes
        </label>
    </li>
</ol>
</div>
<div id="option1Display"><!--jQuery inserts disabled="disabled" and style="display: none;" into <div>-->
<label>Option 2 Question</label>
<ol>
    <li>   
        <label>
            <input name="Option2" type="radio" value="No"><!--jQuery inserts disabled="disabled" and style="display: none;" into <input>-->
            No
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>   
        <label>
            <input name="Option2" type="radio" value="Yes"><!--jQuery inserts disabled="disabled" and style="display: none;" into <input>-->
            Yes
        </label>
    </li>
</ol>
</div>
<div id="option2Display"><!--jQuery inserts disabled="disabled" and style="display: none;" into <div>-->
<!--Additional questions-->
</div>
```

Steps for questions:

1. User selects "Yes" for `Option1`.
2. `option1Display` is shown to user, with `Option2` question.
3. User selects "Yes" for `Option2`.
4. `option2Display` is shown to user with additional questions.
5. If user changes his answer for `Option1` to "No", both `option1Display` and `option2Display` are hidden.
6. Assume user never changed his answer for `Option2` back to "No", so "Yes" is still chosen, even though `option2Display` is now hidden again.
7. If user now changes his answer again for `Option1` back to "Yes", `option1Display` is shown, and the answer to `Option2` is "Yes"; however, `option2Display` is still hidden unless the user changes his answer back to "No" then to "Yes".

I'd like to handle this properly. I hope that's clear. Sorry if it is not, I am not a coder by trade and am just still learning this stuff. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a *single* event handler for both options and check the value of both of them to determine which one(s) to show

Comment: It's a bit hard to get a solid grip on what you're asking without seeing your markup. Do you want to hide the entire `Option2` until `Option1` has a value of "yes"? Or do you want them both visible, but hiding only their child elements?

Comment: Providing a runnable [mcve] here would be a big help

Comment: @charlietfl and agrm, I have edited my question with some markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to show the `option2Display` when the user changes between Yes and No for option 1 by checking the value of option 2 on change of option 1. Note that I made 2 further adjustments in the code: only the `#option1Display` and `#option2Display` elements are shown and hidden as it's not necessary to also show and hide the input elements they contain, and only the inputs are set to disabled and enabled because the `disabled` attribute is meant for input elements and not for e.g. a `<div>`. Note that it's also not necessary to use separate `$(document).ready()` handlers for each `click()` event and a separate script tag, everything can belong to a single `$(document).ready()` event.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='Option1']").on("change", function() {
      if (this.value == "Yes") {
        $('#option1Display').show();
        $('#option1Display input').removeAttr("disabled");
        if ($("input[name='Option2']:checked").val() == "Yes") {
          $('#option2Display').show();
          $('#option2Display input').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
      } else {
        $('#option1Display, #option2Display').hide();
        $('#option1Display input, #option2Display input').attr("disabled", "disabled");
      }
    });
    $("#option1Display").hide();
    $("#option1Display input").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $("input[name='Option2']").on("change", function() {
      if (this.value == "Yes") {
        $('#option2Display').show();
        $('#option2Display input').removeAttr("disabled");
      } else {
        $('#option2Display').hide();
        $('#option2Display input').attr("disabled", "disabled");
      }
    });
    $("#option2Display").hide();
    $("#option2Display input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Option 1 Question</label>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input name="Option1" type="radio" value="No">
        No
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input name="Option1" type="radio" value="Yes">
        Yes
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div id="option1Display">
  <label>Option 2 Question</label>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input name="Option2" type="radio" value="No">
        No
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input name="Option2" type="radio" value="Yes">
        Yes
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div id="option2Display">option2Display
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Going to take me a day to implement, so if I have problems I'll report back. And thanks for the further explanations of how to refactor the code. This is all new to me. :)